# How to create list column with alias in polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I have table which has some columns in it . I need to run some rules to match data with incoming data and provide score  .

I am trying to create list of score  and find best out of it but below mentioned piece is not running . it is giving error

```
import polars as pl
import jaro


def test_polars():
    name='savah'
    data = {"first_name": ['sarah', 'purnima'], "last_name": ['vats', 'malik']}
    df = pl.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
    df = (df.with_columns(
        [
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name") == name).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("E_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("last_name") == name).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("E_LN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name").str.slice(0, 3) == name[0:3]).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("F3_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name").map_elements(
                lambda first_name: jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(first_name, name)) >= 0.8).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias(
                "CMP80_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("last_name").map_elements(
                lambda first_name: jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(first_name, name)) >= 0.9).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias(
                "CMP90_LN"),

        ]
    )
    .with_columns(
        [
            ([980 * pl.col("E_FN") * pl.col("E_LN") ,
              990 * pl.col("E_FN") * pl.col("CMP80_FN")
              ]).alias ( "score"),

        ]
    ))

    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_polars()


C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Scripts\python.exe "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py" 
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ first_name ┆ last_name │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ str       │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ sarah      ┆ vats      │
│ purnima    ┆ malik     │
└────────────┴───────────┘
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py", line 37, in <module>
    test_polars()
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py", line 28, in test_polars
    ]).alias ( "score"),
       ^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'alias'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you mean [`pl.concat_list()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.concat_list.html#polars.concat_list)?

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code

```
import polars as pl
import jaro


def test_polars():
    fname='sarah'
    lname = 'vats'
    data = {"first_name": ['sarah', 'purnima'], "last_name": ['vats', 'malik']}
    df = pl.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
    df = (df.with_columns(
        [
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name") == fname).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("E_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("last_name") == lname).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("E_LN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name").str.slice(0, 3) == fname[0:3]).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("F3_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("first_name").map_elements(
                lambda first_name: jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(first_name, fname)) >= 0.8).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias(
                "CMP80_FN"),
            (pl.when(pl.col("last_name").map_elements(
                lambda first_name: jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(first_name, lname)) >= 0.9).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias(
                "CMP90_LN"),

        ]
    )
    .with_columns(
        [ pl.concat_list(980 * pl.col("E_FN")  ,
                         970 * pl.col("E_LN") ).alias("score")



        ]
    ))

    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_polars()
```